# "Flatten" nested futures

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-thread, future

I have a helper function which I use to "flatten" nested futures into a single future:

EDIT: Renamed "fold" to "flatten" as suggested.

I'm using the futures from the boost library:

```
template<typename T>
auto flatten(boost::unique_future<T>&& f) -> boost::unique_future<decltype(f.get().get())>
{
    auto shared_f = boost::shared_future<T>(std::move(f));
    return async(launch_policy::deferred, [=]() mutable
    {
        return shared_f.get().get();
    });
}
```

It is used like this:

```
auto nested_future_result = async([]() -> boost::shared_future<int>
{
    auto tmp = async([]
    {
        return 1;
    });
    return boost::shared_future<int>(std::move(tmp));    
});

boost::unique_future<int> future_result = flatten(nested_future_result);
int result = future_result.get();
```

The problem is that this only works if I convert the "nested" future into a `shared_future`. Is there any nice way to get around it? What I would like is something like:

```
auto future_result = flatten(async([]
{
    return async([]
    {
        return 1;
    }); 
}));

int result = future_result.get();
```

Secondly, I am a bit unsure of the name for the method. Any opinions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: I don't understand how you got `boost::unique_future` to cooperate with `std::async` so I replaced all instances of `boost::unique_future` with `std::future`. The code has been tested and works on my end.)

The issue is that lambda expressions either capture by value (which really means capture by copy) or by reference (not applicable here as we want to tie the lifetime of the future to our closure), whereas `std::future` is move-only. The answer to that is usually `std::bind`, although in this case `std::async` has a built-in `bind`-like functionality:

```
template<typename T>
auto fold(std::future<T>&& f)
-> std::future<decltype(f.get().get())>
{
    return std::async(std::launch::deferred, [](std::future<T>&& f)
    {
        return f.get().get();
    }, std::move(f));
}
```

I don't have a good name to recommend I'm afraid. If the template perhaps worked recursively to transform any `std::future<std::future<std::future<...std::future<T>...>>>` to `std::future<T>` then perhaps I'd call if `flatten_future`. Or perhaps simply `flatten`, since after all it only accepts an `std::future` in the first place.

---

Assuming we already have a unary `async`:

```
template<typename Functor, typename Arg, typename... Args>
auto async(Functor&& functor, Arg&& arg, Args&&.... args)
-> decltype( async(std::bind(std::forward<Functor>(functor)
    , std::forward<Arg>(arg), std::forward<Args>(args)...)) )
{
    return async(std::bind(std::forward<Functor>(functor)
        , std::forward<Arg>(arg), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: I wrote my own async. Just realized that I shouldn't have prefixed with `std`.

Comment: Could you add that comment to your answer, it's hard to read without formatting.

Comment: Just as a quick question, why doesn't the standardized `std::async` flatten? It seems like a rather natural thing...

Comment: @ronag It was also buggy! Now fixed.

Comment: @ronag I think this has to do with the philosophy of "Don't pay for what you don't ask". I'm not sure launching a deferred task just to peel a future is always desirable. (If however the task is in fact not deferred that could be useful. I really don't know though.) All in all, the whole interface of `std::future` and `std::async` leaves much to be desired in terms of compositions and the like. (Which, admittedly, is by design.)

Comment: Thanks! Now I just have to figure out how to get something like this working on VS2010.

Comment: @ronag Whoops! Sorry about that. Boost.Preprocessor can help in this respect if you're willing to use (and perhaps learn) that. Perhaps this should be another question (and now I'm wondering if there isn't one already about that).

Comment: np, I forgot to tag with VS2010.